# React: FormData not sending image data to Flask backend

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am trying to upload an image, but the form data simply doesn't append the file data to my request.

Front end:

```
const form = new FormData()
form.append('files[]', file)
form.append("woor","w")
console.log(file)
const header = {
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
}
axios.post(
   action,
   form,
   header
).then(({ data: response }) => {})
```

Flask backend:

```
def upload():
    print(request.form)
    print(request.json)    
    return {"body":[{"value":"fdd", "label":"fdaad"}]}
```

The backend prints out `ImmutableMultiDict([('woor', 'w')])` but not the file, `console.log` does show the file data
I have also tried `{"file":file}` and `{"file[]":file}`

EDIT:
`file` is not an array. It looks like a `dict` to me from `console.log()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently came across the same Issue, the answer might be suprisingly simple, you access the file with `request.files` instead of `request.form` in flask.
Here is also a link to the SO question where I had the same Issue, figured it out after a few days: [Dropzone.js not sending the file when adding additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749460/dropzone-js-not-sending-the-file-when-adding-additional-data)

Answer (score 0):

The file object that you are passing to append form must be not correct .`yourFileInputField.files` gives you the array of selected files.
**For Single File**

```
let files=yourFileInputField.files; //returns the list of files
form.append('files', files[0])
```

**for Multiple files**

```
let files=yourFileInputField.files; //returns the list of files

files.forEach(function(file,index){
  form.append('files['+index+']',file)
})
```

Comment: The file object is actually not an array- so `file[0]` is not needed. I tried appending `("files":file)` but that didn't work either

Comment: the problem is probably in your file object can you describe/show how you are  getting the file object from the fileInput.

Comment: I am using a image upload library, and the file is passed as a parameter - I am not sure how the image data is converted. This is what `console.log(file)` shows me `File {name: "image.jpg", lastModified: 1610839352744, lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 16 2021 18:22:32 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 679727, …}
`

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked that many are facing this issue.
In my case, I had multiple header parameter where payload was in formData. So I used this approach:

```
      let formData = new FormData();
      if(e && e[0]){
        formData.append('file', e[0])
      }
    
      const updatePromise = props.uploadImage(formData, payload);
      updatePromise.then((res: any) => {
        props.getEntry({ id: params.id });
      });
      return updatePromise;
```